# How to create the below attached UI using CG classes in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

How to create this kind of UI?

[image]

**So far, I end up creating the same UI like below**.

[image]

I am not sure, how to curve that yellow colored border as in the above reference.

Comment: you should add a mask, add that line from (0,0) to (0,heigth) and after that add a mask for the complete thing

Comment: If you provide your current code I think I can add your needed solution

Comment: @ReinierMelian, thanks for your comments. I am using [this](https://github.com/aaronn/UIView-Borders-Swift) 3rd party classes to add a border to the specific positions in a `UIView`. Also, I have set `cornerRadius` of the **super** `UIView` and a `UITableView` to `15`.

Comment: There are only three lines of code so far to achieve the above view.

**1st:** `self.viewBackground.addBorder(side: .left, thickness: 3.0, color: UIColor.RGB(r: 254, g: 204, b: 47), leftOffset: 0, rightOffset: 0, topOffset: 10, bottomOffset: 10)` 
**2nd:** `self.viewBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0` 
**3rd:** `self.tblView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0`

Comment: did you fixed then?

Comment: @ReinierMelian, no. Not yet. I don't figure out how to get that curve? I believe I should drop using that 3rd party library and write the curve code for my own.

Comment: if you use a mask for your tableView instead of using cornerRadius must solve your problem

Comment: Is there any example out there?

Comment: I will post an answer with a basic example

Comment: Added answer let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply adding a border layout and adding a mask you can achieve what you need

**Full Example (only relevant code)**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var selectedIndex : Int = -1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.tableView.layer.borderWidth = 3
    }

    func bezierPathWithShape(rect:CGRect,cornerRadius:CGFloat) ->UIBezierPath
    {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: cornerRadius, height: cornerRadius))
        return path
    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let mask = CAShapeLayer(layer: self)
        mask.path = self.bezierPathWithShape(rect: self.tableView.bounds, cornerRadius: 15).cgPath
        self.tableView.layer.mask = mask
        self.tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I think you can use your 3er party library changing the top offset and bottom offset to 0, try it @Hemang

Comment: Thank you so much! It is just working as per the need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it.

Take a view which is superView to both the tableView and the lines.

Add cornerRadius, then set `clipToBounds = true` for the superView.

It will clip the lines according to the cornerRadius.